# How to get the component name from a Proxy in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm implementing onErrorCaptured in a Vue component. It has 3 parameters `(error: unknown, instance: ComponentPublicInstance, info: string)`. instance actually ends up being a Proxy. Since the error bubbles up to the component that I'm implementing the onErrorCaptured in, I am trying to get the name of the component that threw the error.

I'm pretty sure that using the router will work in most cases `const throwingComponentName = router.currentRoute.value.name`.

However, how do I get the name of the component from the `instance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your component has its `name` option defined, you can access it from `instance._.type.name`:

```js
onErrorCaptured((err, instance, info) => {
  console.log('component name', instance._?.type?.name)
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-comp-name-in-error-handler?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Since `instance._` is technically an internal/undocumented property, use it with caution, as it could be refactored/removed in a future release. This works as of `vue@3.2.37`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Small tweak got it working for me `instance._?.type?.__name`